How to calculate the frequency of bigrams on fixed size windows
I am computing the frequency of bigrams given a list of token files tokenized_corpus = ['tokens_A.pickle', 'tokens_B.pickle', ...] where every tokens_X file unpickles as ['x', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ñ']. A list of bigrams as a list of tuples as input_bigrams=[('o', 'q'), ('x', 'q'), ('x', 'b'), ('a', 'b')] and a window size as window_size = 5.
The expected output for windows of size 5 are:
['x', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'd']... and so on. Then for this case the bigrams ('x', 'b') and ('a', 'b') count's to 1.
My goal is to optimize the following function in order avoid RAM overload because I will be running several pickle files (1GB each). My approach is the following:
def generate_word_windows(tokens, window_size):
    for i in range(len(tokens) - window_size + 1):
        yield tokens[i:i+window_size]

def bigram_frequencies(input_bigrams, tokenized_corpus, window_size):
    bigram_frequency = defaultdict(int)
    for token_file in tokenized_corpus:
        with open(token_file, 'rb') as file:
            while True:
                try:
                    tokens = pickle.load(file)
                    for window in generate_word_windows(tokens, window_size):
                        for bigram in input_bigrams:
                            if all(word in window for word in bigram):
                                bigram_frequency[bigram] += 1
                except EOFError:
                    break
    return bigram_frequency

input_bigrams = [('o', 'q'), ('x', 'q'), ('x', 'b'), ('a', 'b')]
tokenized_corpus = ['tokens_A.pickle', 'tokens_B.pickle']
window_size = 5

bigram_distributions = bigram_frequencies(input_bigrams, tokenized_corpus, window_size)

print('Output:')
print(*[f'{word}\n' for word in bigram_distributions.items()])


What I'm doing is to iterate over the pickle files, create a window of size 5 and iterate over it. Then, for all windows I iterate over every bigram and check if the words in every bigram exist in the window, if it does then I count it.
How can I improve this program?
